# Отладка программы на Qt

Tags: c++, qt, отладка

Пишу программу использованием qt 5.5. допустим есть функция Foo(). В режиме Выпуска эта функция не должна вызываться, а в режиме отладки - должна. Как это сделать, как должен выглядеть макрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто оберните вызов нужной функции:

```
#if QT_DEBUG
  Foo();
#endif
```

Comment: #ifdef QT_DEBUG
  Foo();
#endif

Comment: `#ifndef NDEBUG`